# Skimage version 0.13.1 shows import error while importing "io" module

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am using python version 3.6.2 and working on image processing. My problem is when I run python through cmd it imports io module of skimage without error but when I import it through python Idle it shows module error that no module name io. Can anyone please enlighten me why is this happening? For more understanding i'm putting screenshots of both the cases.

Through cmd:
[image]

Through Python Idle:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem got solved by reinstalling each and every supporting package.